# How to load google ads using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

In my site i want to load google ads using jquery ajax,Here i am using php code igniter for developing sites.Page contents are load by using jquery ajax,with in that content i want to load google ads.

Thanks

Comment: That's nice. What's your question?

Comment: When you sign up for Google adsense, they give you instructions for adding the necessary javascript to your page.  What do you want to do special that would require jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the page loading time, and that is the only reason for trying to use ajax then why don't you try putting your adsense code in footer.
You can use CSS and position the wrapper div if you want to show the code elsewhere(just a trial thing though).

**Edit:** You can even try [this](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666?hl=en)